# Custom Slot wildcard value?

Tags: wildcard, alexa-skills-kit

First off, I do not want to use AMAZON.Literal as it is for US only (I'm UK based) and I doubt it will be supported much longer.

I need a wildcard slot to allow users to say a place name (name of a shop for example), followed by the city.

City is easy, no problem.

The issue is the place name. I have a custom slot, but I can't list every shop in every city in the values.

I put a value of `any` in, which kind of works, but in my response, I'm only getting the last word if the user says a name that contains a few words e.g. `Pound Land` would just return `Land`.

Has anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As of 2018, you can use phrases to get user input that you may not be able to predefine.

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "SearchIntent",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "Query",
          "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery"
        },
        {
          "name": "CityList",
          "type": "AMAZON.US_CITY"
        }
      ],
      "samples": [
        "search for {Query} near me",
        "find out {Query}",
        "search for {Query}",
        "give me details about {CityList}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/a2716002-0f50-4587-b038-31ce631c0c07/enhance-speech-recognition-of-your-alexa-skills-with-phrase-slots-and-amazon-searchquery

Answer (score 0):

When using custom slot types, AWS may return values from outside of the list yet it will try to map to the values. You can "hack" this behavior by providing a huge list of possible values. Maybe try to scrap a list of places and use that. I once tried with a list of 3000 landmarks and it was definitely returning slot values that were not in the list. The recognition was not great but I had an acoustic similarity function that allowed me to retrieve items from the list when needed. That was a while ago when they first talked about deprecating Amazon.LITERAL but eventually left it so I didn't have to worry about this.

Comment: Yea, that's not going to work. I'd have to get the users city first, then do the scraping which is going to take time. Or I scrape shops for every major city in the US, UK and Germany? Not gonna happen.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I scrapped a few websites for major landmark names. Again, you don't *need* to add every possible shop, just some large number of *representative* names from every of your locales. The more you add, the more things it will recognize (and the longer it will take the training).

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this post, found an article while searching the same issue that gives tips on how to use slot types better:

https://medium.com/voiceflow/tips-and-gotchas-using-alexa-custom-slots-b88f97f26b06